# Android, Write a char array to sharedpreference without creating a String

Tags: android, security, sharedpreferences

I was wondering if there is a way to put data in Sharedpreferences on Android without creating a String. I have a sensitive char array(base64 encoding) that I would like to store in an encrypted Sharepreference but I would like to avoid creating a String(using putString())  in the process given that they are immutable. Is there a way to accomplish this?
Thanks!

Comment: `SharedPreferences` are not a particularly good storage mechanism for something like this. Use SQLCipher for Android. Or, find [an existing library](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=crypt) that offers encrypted storage, focusing on those that offer `CharSequence`-based APIs.

Comment: Also note that `base64` is NOT an encryption. It's not even close.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I am reviewing an application where there is an "over-usage" of Java Strings and I am looking for alternatives to propose to them. I will have a look at the libraries you proposed! Thakns!

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Very true! In this case it is not to bad, the base64 string it self is encrypted first before storage. But yeah, It happens way often than it should that base64 is used as encryption....

Answer (score 0):

Well for this scenario I can suggest you can hide actual content with key-value pattern, just create any significant key for your data at point of entry and set data as value for same and save both in SQL-lite or any supported database, and then retrieve same values using key at your destination.

By this way only key will be shared in internal transaction and data will never reveal on any mid-points.

Hope this will help.

Comment: But if the key value store uses a String as value type then we would still have the same problem? Anyway, I guess away as much as possible from sharedpreferences....

Comment: It's up to you, either you can use key type as long or int and assign hashcode for key.